# How to remove the divider in AlertDialog

Tags: android, android-view, android-theme, android-dialog

I am using **android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog**.However, I'm not able to remove the divider.Can anybody tell me how to remove it? thanks.

[image]

this is my style:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="alertDialogTheme">@style/AppTheme.Dialog.Alert</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.Dialog.Alert" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog.Alert">
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
```

this is my code:

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(mSettingsView.getBaseActivity());
builder.setTitle("Ringtone");
builder.setSingleChoiceItems(list, -1, listener1);
builder.setPositiveButton("OK", listener2);
builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", listener3);
builder.show();
```

Comment: If you don't set the title and buttons, then you won't see the dividers.

Comment: You can create a Custom Alert Dialog instead of this. Check this tutorial: http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-custom-dialog-example/

Answer (score 1):

AlertDialog divider is different in pre-lollipop and lollipop devices. I found, divider colour is Gray in pre-lollipop(pre-material design) devices. So it is visible. But for material design(lollipop) devices, divider colour is transparent, so it seems not visible/present.

To make divider visible across all devices, explicitly make the colour Gray or any other colour.

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());

AlertDialog alertDialog = builder.create();

ListView listView = alertDialog.getListView();

listView.setDivider(new ColorDrawable(Color.GRAY));

listView.setDividerHeight(1);

alertDialog.show();
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the AlertDialog inside a android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment? I always use it this way and I never get the divider in your screen:

```
import android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;

public class MyDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {

    public static MyDialogFragment newInstance(){
        return new MyDialogFragment;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
        // Get the layout inflater
        LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
        // Inflate my custom layout
        View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_custom_layout, null);
        // Initialize my layout components
        ...
        // Build dialog
        builder.setTitle("TITLE")
            .setView(layout)
            .setPositiveButton("OK", listener)
            .setNegativeButton("Cancel", listener);
        return builder.create();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank for your advice.I try to use it inside a android.app.DialogFragment.But it fail again.

Comment: I've compared my `styles.xml` with yours, and I noticed that their identical except for the lines with `windowActionBar` and `windowNoTitle`. I don't have them at all, so can you try to comment them?

Comment: After commenting them, the divider still exist.

Comment: You do not, because you use a custom layout.